# How to receive EMails in C# application?

Tags: c#

I have an application build in C# for reading and saving SMS and MMS, now i want to add another functionality of reading EMails through my C# application using any mail servcies e.g gmail, hotmail or yahoo?
How to do this in C#?

Comment: +1 for calling us "dears"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to implement an IMAP or POP3 client and connect to the external mail server.  You can then read the contents of mailboxes.

Getting started with IMAP: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/imaplibrary.aspx